# I wan't to update laravel 8 to 9 and getting the error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I am getting the error like below code on upgrading the laravel 8.x to 9.x

> spatie/crawler 8.2.0 requires illuminate/collections ^10.0|^11.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/collections[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev, 11.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].
> - spatie/crawler[8.0.1, ..., 8.1.0] require illuminate/collections ^10.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/collections[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev].
> - illuminate/collections 11.x-dev is an alias of illuminate/collections dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
> - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/collections[dev-master, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev, v10.3.0, ..., 10.x-dev], laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/collections and thus cannot coexist with it.
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev].
> - Root composer.json requires spatie/crawler ^8.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/crawler[8.0.0, ..., 8.2.0].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
[1]+  Exit 4                  composer install

My composer file looks  like below code

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^8.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0.1",
    "convertio/convertio-php": "^0.4.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.8.2",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^3.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
    "laravel/helpers": "^1.7.0",
    "laravel/passport": "^11.10.5",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.3.3",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.4.1",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1.53",
    "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "^2.5",
    "phpoffice/phppresentation": "^1.0.0",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.29.0",
    "spatie/laravel-sitemap": "^7.0",
    "torann/geoip": "^3.0",
    "tucker-eric/eloquentfilter": "^3.3.0",
    "spatie/crawler": "^8.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2.4",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.9.0"        
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: What have you done so far? assuming you followed the upgrade guide.

Comment: I have just changed ```"spatie/laravel-sitemap": "^7.0",``` to ```"spatie/laravel-sitemap": "^6.4.2",``` and it will fix the issue for me